# Yii 2.0 Select Pre-selected values from Database

Tags: yii

I have been trying to fix an issue but to no avail but i am sure i will find a solution here. I am using Kartik 2.0 Select extension to do a multiple select. Fine, all working when inserting into the database but i am unable to retrieve the saved records to be displayed as selected back in the select field.

//I have included the kartik widgets already

use kartik\widgets\Select2;

```
<label>Desired Specialization(s)</label>
            <?= $form->field($spec, 'id')->label(false)->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'data' => $model->getAllSpecializations(),
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'You can choose more than one specialization ...'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'multiple' => true
                ],
            ]);

            ?>
        </div>
```

Please, your reply will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: show your model (specialization)  and your controller

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the saved values as the initial data? Like so:

```
'value' => $savedDataArray, // initial value
```

http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-tags

Answer (score 0):

After much digging into the code, i found a way on how to display selected database values into a multi-select option using Yii Select2

**My Model**

```
public function getCandidateLanguage()
    {
        $langValues = (new \yii\db\Query())
                    ->select('c.language_id AS id, l.lang_name')
                    ->from('candidate_language c ')
                    ->innerJoin('languages l','c.language_id = l.id')
                    ->where('c.candidate_id='.$this->candidate_id)
                    ->orderBy('c.language_id')
                    ->all();

            return \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($langValues,'id','lang_name');
    }
```

**My View**
use kartik\widgets\Select2;

```
<?php
         //the line below is to fetch the array key of $model->getCandidateLanguage() array   
         $lang->id = array_keys($model->getCandidateLanguage());  // value to initialize
            echo Select2::widget([
               'model' => $lang,
               'attribute' => 'id',
               'data' => $model->getAllLanguages(),

               'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Choose multiple languages'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'tags' => true,
                ],

            ]);

         ?>
```

Hope it help someone who is facing the same issue.